# Dynamic Menu and Javascript Scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a little submenu in a wordpress site that creates a menu based on sections created via ACF with in a custom post type. There can be any number of these sections within the post and all have a required a main header that i have then used as the ID of each section (see `$name` below). I have used a while loop to create the menu:

```
<?php
  if( have_rows('main_page_content', $case_study->ID) ):
      while ( have_rows('main_page_content', $case_study->ID) ) : the_row();
          $name = get_sub_field( 'main_heading_1' );
          $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
          $name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);
          $name = strtolower($name);
          ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $name ?>" class="case-study-menu"> 
              <?php echo get_sub_field( 'main_heading_1' ) ; ?> 
            </div>
            <script>
             var bbg = jQuery.noConflict();
              bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").click(function() {
                bbg('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").offset().top
                }, 1000);
              });
            </script>
          <?php
      endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

I have used the code below elsewhere in my site simply to cut the headers name down to a single string as each section then uses this as an ID.

```
$name = get_sub_field( 'main_heading_1' );
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
$name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);
$name = strtolower($name);
```

So this works great, but I need to menu to be scroll to each section when clicked. So the javascript will need to use the `$name` and use it to scroll to a div with that ID, so I got this:

```
<script>
 var bbg = jQuery.noConflict();
  bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").click(function() {
    bbg('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

The problem is getting these aspects to work together, I have tried putting the script inside the while loop like below but it just kinda scrolls down like 100px no matter what button you press.

```
<?php
  if( have_rows('main_page_content', $case_study->ID) ):
      while ( have_rows('main_page_content', $case_study->ID) ) : the_row();
          $name = get_sub_field( 'main_heading_1' );
          $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
          $name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $name);
          $name = strtolower($name);
          ?>
            <div id="<?php echo $name ?>" class="case-study-menu"> 
              <?php echo get_sub_field( 'main_heading_1' ) ; ?> 
            </div>
            <script>
             var bbg = jQuery.noConflict();
              bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").click(function() {
                bbg('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").offset().top
                }, 1000);
              });
            </script>
          <?php
      endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

Can any guide me to a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Original had the button and section with an ID of the same nam. Changing the button to a class rather than ID solved the issue

```
<script>
     var bbg = jQuery.noConflict();
      bbg(".<?php echo $name ?>").click(function() {
        bbg('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: bbg("#<?php echo $name ?>").offset().top
        }, 1000);
      });
</script>
```